# how to save output result outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

How to use a php variable outside the loop

how to save output result outside the loop

this variable $jsonrs

this is the result I want it outside the loop

"1""1.jpg""2""2.jpg""3""3.jpg""4""4.jpg"

```
$url =  'https://hentaifox.com/gallery/58769/';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all('!<img class="lazy no_image" data-src="(.*?)"!', $result, $manga_name);

$items = array();

foreach ($manga_name[1] as $key => $manganm) {


    $imag_manga = str_replace('t.jpg','.jpg',$manganm);

    $imagerep = 'https:'.$imag_manga;


    $filename = basename($imagerep);

    $imag_num = str_replace('.jpg','',$filename);

    $array_name = array($imag_num => $filename);

    $json1 = json_encode($imag_num);

    $json2 = json_encode($filename);

    $jsonrs = $json1.$json2;

    print_r($jsonrs);
}
```

Comment: You might want `$jsonrs .=` instead of `$jsonrs =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your end result in `$jsonrs` is a bit unusual, I (am assuming) that you want to JSON encode the list of images, if so then use `$items` to keep a list of each image and then `json_encode()` this list after the loop...

```
foreach ($manga_name[1] as $key => $manganm) {
    $filename = basename($manganm);
    $imag_num = str_replace('t.jpg','',$filename);
    $items[$imag_num] = $filename;
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

will give you

```
{"1":"1t.jpg","2":"2t.jpg","3":"3t.jpg","4":"4t.jpg"}
```